# Problems with operator=

Tags: c++

I built 2 classes, `Multime` (meaning set) and `Array`. I need to overload the `*` operator to do the intersection of sets and assign the result to another set. I decided to overload the `=` operator as well, to solve the latter. This is the header of `Multime`:

```
class Multime{
private:
    Array a;
    int* n;
public:
    Multime();
    Multime(Multime& ob);
    ~Multime();
    void Transformare(Array t);//transforms an array into a set by eliminating duplicates
    int& operator[] (int x);//makes ob[i] return ob.a[i];
    Multime& operator+ (Multime& y);
    Multime& operator=(Multime& y);
    Multime& operator* (Multime& y);
    void Afisare();//outputs the array in the object that called it
};
```

This is the header of Array:

```
class Array{
private:
    int* c;///the array
    int len, capacity;
public:
    Array();
    void Append(int);
    ~Array();
    int& operator[] (int);//makes ob[i] retuen ob.c[i]
    void Afisare();
    void Sortare();//sorts the array
    friend class Multime;
};
```

This is how I overload the = operator:

```
Multime& Multime::operator=(Multime& ob)
{
    if(*n!=0) { 
        std::cout<<"don't overwrite a nonvoid set"; 
        std::cout<<"the result should have been "<<ob.Afisare(); 
        std::cout<<"n="<<*n;
    }
    else
    {
        if(this!=&ob)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<*ob.n; i++)
            {
                a.Append(ob.a[i]);
            }
            *n=*(ob.n);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

This is how I overload the * operator:

```
Multime& Multime::operator* (Multime& y)
{
    Multime q;
    for(int i=0; i<*n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<*y.n; j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==y.a[j])
                q.a.Append(a[i]);
        }
    }
    *q.n=q.a.len;
    *this=q;
    return *this;
}
```

If `mul1` is the `{1, 2, 3}` set (with length 3, of course) and `mul2` is `{-2, 2, 5 9}`, the code:

```
Multime mul5;
mul5=mul1*mul2;
```

outputs

```
don't overwrite a nonvoid set
the result should have been 2 
n=3
```

I'm very confused as to why `n` is `3` although it was just created.

Comment: Please show all the code needed to reproduce the problem. Please show Multime();
    Multime(Multime& ob);` constructors

Comment: Why is `Multime::n` a pointer at all? What does it point at?

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You get the output you do because of this line at the end of `operator*`:

```
*this=q;
```

You're overwriting the `this` parameter (which is `mul1` from the caller), which is not an empty `Multime` object.

Fundamentally, your two `operator*` does not behave as a multiplication operator, because it modifies one of the parameters.  Its behavior is that of an `operator*=` function.  The signature for a member `operator*` would typically be something like

```
Multime Multime::operator*(const Multime& y) const
```

where it won't modify either parameter, and returns a new object.  You can remove that problematic assignment from the end and just end it with `return q;`.

Comment: You haven't shown all of the relevant code (like constructors).  This answer addresses the immediate problem but there are others lurking.